# I would like to animate a CSS change using .attr to change the link

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, attr

I have this piece of script to change the CC, but the change is instantaneous, and I would like to animate it (to make it smooth), any idea of how this could be achieved?

script:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var css = 'x';
    $('#button').button();
    $('#button').click( function() {
        if (css == 'x') {
            $('#button').button('option', 'label', 'change to css x');
            $('link[href="css/x.css"]').attr('href', 'css/y.css');
            css= 'y';
        }
        else if (css== 'y') {
            $('#button').button('option', 'label', 'change to css y');
            $('link[href="css/y.css"]').attr('href', 'css/x.css');
            css= 'x';           
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be considered bad practice, but you could try to add temporarily :

```
* {
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

Then, perform your CSS change, then remove this rule.

I didn't test it, it might not work at all. Just an idea.